# Inject @Value inside into @PropertySource in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have two application property profiles `dev` and `prod`. I set the profile active in my application properties file as `spring.profiles.active=dev`

I want to dynamic load of my classpath properties file according to the active profile. so I want to inject the `@Value` annotation into my classpath variable as below:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application-@Value('${spring.profiles.active:}').properties"})
```

is it possible to do that??

Comment: Spring boot loads the profile-specific properties file by default. There's no need to specify any `@PropertySource` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one file application.properties where you have to specify the profile like this spring.profiles.active=dev

And than create dedicated files for each profile where you have specific configs.
application-dev.properties
application-uat.propertiea

Than you can use Value annotation and it will be picked automatically.

See this:https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-profiles-1